# Jqgrid - saving data to local array

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I use jqgrid to correct some information

My code is:

```
        var lastsel;
        $("#list4").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            height: 250,
            colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
            colModel:[
                {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, editable:true},
                                    ......
                {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, editable:true}        
            ],
            onSelectRow: function(id)
            {
                if(id && id!==lastsel)
                {
                    if (lastsel!=undefined)
                        $('#list4').jqGrid('saveRow',lastsel);
                    $('#list4').jqGrid('editRow',id,true);
                    lastsel=id;
                }
            },
            viewrecords: false,
            multiselect: false,
            caption: "Manipulating Array Data",
            editurl:'clientArray',
            cellSubmit: 'clientArray'
        });
        mydata = [
            {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
                             ...
            {id:"9",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}
            ];
        for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++)
            jQuery("#list4").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata[i]);
```

But after editing cell I can't see any changes in mydata.
How can realize realtime mapping to mydata?

Answer (score 1):

I use this code for onSelectRow method

```
onSelectRow: function(id)
{
    if(id && id!==lastsel)
    {
        if (lastsel!=undefined)
            $('#list4').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
        $('#list4').jqGrid('editRow',id,true,false,false,false,false,function(i)
        {
            console.log($("#list4").getRowData(i));
            mydata[i]=$("#list4").getRowData(i);
        });
        lastsel=id;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a threaded forum.  You should edit your original question, not answer it.  Take the tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour